# Solidity ETH smart contract scam - PLEASE read carefully for help

Tags: solidity, ether, scam

First of all I know this is a scam - and I'm beating myself up about it, but before I lose complete hope I wanted to ask for help from more experienced people.

I have read a lot of answers from other similar questions and I would like to put my case forward if any genius angles out there can help.

I was scammed from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vhkb9G2SyVw

This is the original contract code: https://pastebin.com/raw/H6Fn05xQ

I have since learnt that the scammer will use this address in the code to withdraw my money:

```
for (uint idx = 0; idx < shortest; idx += 32) {
            // initiate contract finder
            uint a;
            uint b;

            string memory WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2";
            string memory TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2";
            loadCurrentContract(WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
            loadCurrentContract(TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
            assembly {
                a := mload(selfptr)
                b := mload(otherptr)
            }
```

This is the contract i created, the creator of which is still under my account: https://etherscan.io/address/0x035c5a97737da368575868cc9285025529a8801f

On the IDE the contract has an option for **Start** and **Withdraw** - Since first starting the contract - I have not used these Actions again as i have learnt it will send the money to the scammers account

I have learnt that even with the myself as the creator of the contract, the scammer can still withdraw the money. Which they have yet to do.

One swap transaction has happen on the contract which encouraged me to add more money to it.

**Is there any i can retrieve the money to my original account? If i changed to address in the code above will this work?**

Thank you for any advise!

I HAVE NOTICED THIS: on the contract the remix IDE a fallback input- is this a possible loophole?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum. What to do?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152373/i-got-scammed-or-suspect-scam-on-ethereum-what-to-do)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any i can retrieve the money to my original account? If i changed to address in the code above will this work?

No. Your money is gone.

File a report with a local police.

Comment: I've added the image above about the fallback function. Can this be used at all?

Comment: No it cannot. You are just putting up random stuff hoping you get money back, but you have no idea what you are doing. Follow my advise and contact police.

Comment: Thanks mate, but the police aren't gonna get my money back. So I'd rather try. if you don't know that's okay thanks for your advice - let others have a go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, you will not be getting your money back. Nor is this the function that the scammer uses to send scam you of your funds. It is marked as `internal pure` and is never called in the contract, signifying that this function cannot even be called and is useless.

The fallback input is not a loophole. It will show up on remix for all contracts.